# How to add browser history in UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, xcode4.5, browser-history

In safari or any browser when we press the back button, the previous page opens. But when we hold the button for a while, the browser history opens up. How do we code this in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

A view controller for this purpose is not available out of the box but is really easy to achieve. first thing you need to do is create a data container of of all websites your browser has visited using either with a `NSMutableArray` or a `pList` saved within your user document folder.

Then within your `UIWebViewDelegate`, `webViewDidStartLoad` get called each time the page has finished loading. Use the webView object to get the URL and then save to the data container:

```
webView.request.URL.absoluteString; // save string
```

Am assuming you have a button control to go back and forward, add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` object which listens for long presses on a button. Once this has been triggered create a `UITableViewController` and push that on to the stack with `pushViewController` method and pass the data container of URLs.